# Why is the behavior of the "atr" function different from the documented behavior?

Tags: pine-script

pine-script has a built-in function "atr"
The [official documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_atr) says the following

> Function atr (average true range) returns the RMA of true range. True
> range is max(high - low, abs(high - close[1](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_atr)), abs(low - close[1](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_atr))).

However, when I try to reproduce this formula in code, I get incomparably different results

```
length = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=22)
atr = atr(length)
plotchar(atr, "ATR FUNCTION", "") // 4.9
plotchar(max(high[length] - low[length], abs(high[length] - close[1]), abs(low[length] - close[1])),'ATR FORMULA') // 10.3
```

Why do I get so many different results, it would seem, when working with the same total code?

I tried to use the code without specifying the offset, but I still get results that do not match the attr function

```
plotchar(max(high - low, abs(high - close[1]), abs(low - close[1])),'ATR FORMULA')
```

Answer (score 1):

And I figured it out myself, there is another function superimposed on the top of the formula [RMA](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_rma)

And the final code is obtained to reproduce such

```
plotchar(rma(max(high - low, abs(high - close[1]), abs(low - close[1])),length),'ATR FORMULA')
```